# How to get this selected text into DIV instead of textarea, and also collect one by one all selected part into div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is a simple script that is working to get selected text in text-area okay.

But i want a few change here.

i want to get these selected text into div someclass instead of textarea, and every time when i select text and click on `Get Selection` button then add selected text into new div someclass.

Just like this:

```
<div class='someclass'> the first time selection</div>
<div class='someclass'> second selection </div>
<div class='someclass'> third selection </div>
<div class='someclass'> fourth selection </div>

... and so on
```

Plz i don't know how can i do that plz make it solve.

**My Whole Code is Here:**

```js
 // Function to get the Selected Text  
            function getSelectedText() { 
                var selectedText = ''; 
  
                // window.getSelection 
                if (window.getSelection) { 
                    selectedText = window.getSelection(); 
                } 
                // document.getSelection 
                else if (document.getSelection) { 
                    selectedText = document.getSelection(); 
                } 
                // document.selection 
                else if (document.selection) { 
                    selectedText =  
                    document.selection.createRange().text; 
                } else return; 
                // To write the selected text into the textarea 
                document.testform.selectedtext.value = selectedText; 
            }
```

```html
      <p>Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button</p> 
          
          <br>
     
     <input type="button"
               value="Get Selection" 
               onmousedown="getSelectedText()"> 
        
        <!--Form to show the selected text as output-->
        <form name="testform"> 
            <textarea name="selectedtext" 
                      rows="5"
                      cols="20"></textarea>
```

Thanks in advance and Love you plz solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per what i understand that you need to append the selection text to a new element

here we go , check out the snippet

```js
// Function to get the Selected Text  
function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = '';
  // #### create a new element with variable (nw) #### //
  var nw = document.createElement("div"); // Element's tag
  nw.className = "NEWCLASS"; // Element's class name
  nw.style.textAlign = "center"; // some applied style

  // window.getSelection 
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
  }
  // document.getSelection 
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
  }
  // document.selection 
  else if (document.selection) {
    selectedText =
      document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  // #### get the Selected text appended to body #### //
  nw.innerHTML = selectedText;
  document.body.appendChild(nw); // Append element to body

}
```

```html
<p>Select any part of this sentence and press the button. Select any part of this sentence and press the button. Select any part of this sentence and press the button</p>

<br>

<input type="button" value="Get Selection" onmousedown="getSelectedText()">
```